# Call a php model function in js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to call some **php** model function in on onclick attribute like this:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="my-button" onclick="setCookie()"></button>
```

**JS:**

```
function setCookie() {
   ...
}
```

PHP Model:

```
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('aa', 'vv', '60')
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to invoke server-side functionality from a client-side event, without loading a new page context, then the technology you're looking for is "AJAX".  It's *pretty broad*, but at the very least you should be able to use that term to find some tutorials and examples.

Comment: Yes, thank you for you reply, i have mentioned it in tags "ajax" but i don't know how to call a model inside it

Comment: Well, how would you otherwise "call a model" in your PHP code?  What do you *mean* by that?  How is it in any way different to "call a model" in a PHP script invoked by an AJAX call than one invoked by a page load?

Comment: Well, the function that i have in my model is this one `"Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set($name, $value, $period)"` so i can call it where i want and it works, what i need is to execute it just when a user click on my button, so when he click i set some cookie

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to point out, that javascript itself can handle cookies, so you don't have to use PHP function for this.
For example:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
```

You can find more on this topic [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

If you use models and MVC structure It really depends on how you process your requests. In my answer I will asume, you don't use any fancy framework.
Your html part will be almost the same (I erased inline javascript, the ID itself is enough)

```
<button id="my-button"></button>
```

In javascript, if you use jQuery framework, it will look like this:

```
$("#my-button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "doStuff.php",
        data: { setSomething: "value"}
        success: function(result){
        // what to do after php is done
        alert("all done!");
    }});
});
```

To catch this call and use proper function you can use for example (and in most simple example) isset function. So in your **doStuff.php**

```
...
If (isset($_POST["setSomething"]))
{
   // do some php stuff, echo results
}
```